# Creating new cell values for each new value in a range

Tags: vba, loops

I'm having trouble with a specific process.
In column H, there are a bunch of different numbers. I'm looking for a loop, that for each newfound value in the column, counts how many times the value occur in that column, and put's the counted value in the next worksheet "Statistik".

I do have a solution were I make a code for each individual number in the column, but i'm looking for a loop, since there are 28 different values ind that column.

[Image of my workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is5gJ.png)

Does anyone have a bright solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `COUNTIF`. Either as a formula or in your VBA code (`Application.CountIf()`).

In your case `=COUNTIF(H:H, [UNIQUE_VALUE])` where unique value is the value you want to extract. To get unique values you have two options. One is to copy unique values from H:H to your Statistik sheet as follows:

1. Click the **Data** Ribbon Menu
2. Select the **Advanced** Button in the Sort & Filter section
3. Fill in the dialog Box, **Copy to another location**, List range **H:H**, Copy to **Some column in Statistik sheet* making sure you tick **Unique records only**

Other option to get unique values is detailed here https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list

For more information about `COUNTIF`
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: I'll try take a look at that. :-)
I'm just wondering, if I in row 3 finds a 4, counts, that there are 11 4's, and create a new cell with the value 11. If I in row 6 fx, finds 4 again, would I then end up with a new cell with the value 11 again. Cause I don’t want that to happen. :-)

Comment: Well, definitely I will create a helper column in your Statistik sheet (look my edited answer) with a list of unique values, let say unique values are in Satistik!A column, then you can do `Satistik!B1 =COUNTIF(SourceSheet!H:H, Satistik!A1)` and so for each row of unique values. You can hide column A if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to output only 1 key and value

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetCount()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")                    'change as appropriate
        Dim arr(), i As Long
        arr = Intersect(.Columns("H"), .UsedRange) '<=== Specify exact range in H to loop over if you want including header
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) + 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'assuming header to ignore otherwise start at 1
            If Not dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                dict.Add arr(i, 1), 1  '<==== if value not seen before add to dictionary with value of 1
            Else
                dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) + 1 ' <====== if seen before add 1 to the existing count
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("Statistik")
        .Range("A1") = "StudyBoard_ID"
        .Range("B1") = "Count"
        .Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
        .Range("B2").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did the above make sense?

Comment: Thank you. Yes the overall does make sense, I just have to make it all come together.

Comment: Please let me know what else is required.